# Trying to static link with a Python3 Cython C extension

Tags: python, c, compilation, cython, libraries

So, i am trying to static link a cython app so that i can deploy it on my server clusters without having to install a lot of libraries.

I can compile the binary fine, but when i run it on another machine i get this message prompted:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = './netd.sh'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/root/netd.sh'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/root/netd.sh'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000000b52380 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

This error indicates that the application is actually not statically linked, causing it to error because it cant find the required libraries.

When compiling i run this command (which succeeds fine):

```
gcc -v /root/netd/bot/bot.c -o /root/netd/bot/netd.sh -static $(pkg-config --libs --static --cflags python3) -pthread -march=x86-64 -Os -I/usr/include/python3.9 -L/usr/lib/python3.9 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpython3.9 -lexpat -lz -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lc
```

And on the compiling machine it does run fine, without any problems.

I hope anyone can help me, i tried to provide as much info as possible but since im new on this forum please notify me if you need more context.

I have tried minimizing my application, to the point of only using standard python libraries, but sadly it resulted in the same error, giving me indication that it is not a code issue, but a compiling issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is because Cython embedded executables are not truly independent - they don't include any modules it depends on. In this case it depends on the Python standard library. There really isn't an easy fix for it. Cython just isn't the best tool for producing standalone executables